# Tree node icon dissappears when i click on it

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtree, treecellrenderer

[image]  /*  when i am clicking the tree node (EX:WEBLOGIC is selected) the node icon disappears,but the other icons(Non selected) are coming.please help me out  to solve this issue.This is a swing based program*/

```
class ColorRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer
{
  public ColorRenderer()
  {
    super();
  }

  public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus)
  {
    try
    {
      Component cell = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
      RTGTreeNode treeNode = (RTGTreeNode) value;
      GraphUniqueKeyDTO graphUniqueKeyDTO = treeNode.getGraphUniqueKeyDTO();

      /*Default Icon not needed.*/
      setIcon(null);

      if (graphUniqueKeyDTO == null)
      {
        return cell;
      }

      String nodeName = treeNode.toString();

      if (!leaf)
      {
        cell.setFont(NSColor.mediumPlainFont());
        if (selected)
        {
          cell.setForeground(Color.black);
          cell.setBackground(new Color(128, 0, 0));
        }
        else
        {
          Color color = treeNode.getNodeColor();

          if (treeNode.getTreeViewToolTip() != null)
            nodeName = treeNode.getTreeViewToolTip();
          openIcon = treeNode.getImgIcon();
          if(openIcon!=null){
              setIcon(openIcon);
              setLeafIcon(openIcon);

          }


          if(color == null)
            cell.setForeground(NSColor.leftPaneGroupTitleColor());
          else
            cell.setForeground(color);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        cell.setFont(NSColor.smallPlainFont());
        if (selected)
        {
          cell.setForeground(Color.black);
          cell.setBackground(new Color(128, 0, 0));
        }
        else
        {
          cell.setForeground(NSColor.leftPaneGraphTitleColor());
        }
      }

      setToolTipText(nodeName);
      JLabel currentCell = (JLabel) cell;
      currentCell.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      return cell;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Log.errorLog("ColorRenderer", "getTreeCellRendererComponent", "", "", "Exception - " + ex);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). There is no picture, BTW.

Comment: I am unable to add the image here,what to do ?

Comment: *"..what to do ?"* Post an MCVE.

Comment: you need to post code and a picture, or you won't get any help

Comment: when i am clicking the tree node the previously set icon automatically disappears.This is the issue.I have made a complete tree for my project .Please help

Comment: @mKorbel  I am offering 5 to 1 odds on 'code loads image using `ImageIcon`'.  ;)

Comment: @OliverWatkins this is my first post and the site asks for 10 reputation to post image . That's why i am helpless.

Comment: @mKorbel yes i'am talking about TreeRenderer

Comment: *"the site asks for 10 reputation to post image"*  A good way to gain reputation is to take advice to post an MCVE.  (But we don't really need the image.)

Comment: @user3804274 [treecellrenderer&imageicon](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjtree%5D+treecellrenderer+imageicon) or [treecellrenderer&icon](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjtree%5D+treecellrenderer+icon), please ask a new question in the case that you'll find out the bug(s)

Comment: @AndrewThompson what is mcve ?Can You please advice me what to do now ?

Comment: @user3804274 can you instead post some code up?

Comment: @user3804274 for SSCCE/MCVE you can to use the built_in Icaons by using `UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon" / "informationIcon" / "warningIcon" / "questionIcon");`

Comment: @OliverWatkins ok.i am updating the question

Comment: @AndrewThompson updated my question .tell me now what to do ?

Comment: *"tell me now what to do"*  Now ***follow the link*** I put in the first comment and read it carefully.  What you posted is not an MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A node in a tree can have a custom icon but most skins have an additional folder like icon next to those nodes in a tree that contain children.  I think you mean the Folder icon next to the node disappears when you click on it.  If the tree asks the model if it has children and the model returns true then the icon is displayed.  When you click on the node and the children are not present the tree removes the icon.

This will happen if you did not implement the getChildren and [isLeaf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#isLeaf%28java.lang.Object%29) method or implemented isLeaf incorrectly.  The isLeaf method tells the JTree UI to draw or not draw the folder icon.  Also make sure [setAsksAllowsChildren()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#setAsksAllowsChildren%28boolean%29) is set the the correct value for your needs and [getChildCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#getChildCount%28java.lang.Object%29) returns the correct value for each node.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.I have solved the issue by taking the help of u .I am Very happy to thank u again.